# Can I use a Schengen visa issued by Finland to visit non-schengen EU countries?

Tags: schengen, croatia, itineraries, finland, change-purpose-of-travel

I got a multiple visit visa from Finnish Embassy to visit a friend, a citizen in Finland. He suggested taking a trip to Croatia; this will affect my itinerary so that less than half of my stay will be in Finland.

This is very important since there is a passport check at the Croatian border and they will stamp incoming and outgoing dates. How can I do this change safely? Does sending a mail to the embassy help? Will they accept this itinerary change?

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have your visa, there is no point in changing it. You would only do so if the was a substantial, material change to the circumstances of your visit.

In this case, your situation is such that your travel itinerary has changed, even though you are still primarily traveling to Finland. You do not need to notify the embassy or ask for a visa change.

Croatia offers visa exemption for Schengen holders under these conditions:

- You must hold a multiple entry visa, valid for all Schengen states
- The visa period must cover your stay in Croatia
- You must not have used all your days in the 90/180 rule (in other words, you cannot spend 90 days in Schengen states, and then use the same visa for Croatia, you would need to exit the Schengen zone completely)
- For double-entry visas, you must have one entry remaining.

From the information you have provided, you meet all the criterion, so enjoy your stay.

Comment: Your answer is a bit wrong. Finland absolutely doesn't care about how you spend your time in Croatia since Croatia is a non-Schengen country. Even if OP didn't travel to Finland at all and instead traveled directly to Croatia there would be no need to change the visa.

Comment: Finland might be concerned if they believed that the Schengen visa was granted through deception. But staying **shorter** than planned is less of a concern than staying longer.

Comment: @JonathanReez so even if we stay for travel totally for say 10 days and we stay for 7 days in Croatia (Entrance and exit from Finland) there would be NO problem?

Comment: the suggested change in itinerary is material. Since we plan to travel for about 10 days and the Croatia part will take more than 6-7 days.

Comment: Croatia is immaterial here. You might as well go to Finland for 3 days and spend the rest of your time home. Finland would only care if you went to other Schengen countries.